# Optimizing query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, indexing

Honestly, I really thought this was a simple thing. However, my MySQL query performance is horrendous and I'm out of ideas why.

Three tables: person (10,000,000 rows), employer (50,000 rows), person_achievements (250,000 rows)

```
Person (indexes ix_EmpID)
ID int (primary)
Emp_ID int
Full_Name varchar(250)

Employer (indexes ix_ID (ID) and ix_SectID (Sector_ID) and ix_Name) 
ID int (primary)
Sector_ID int
Name varchar (250)

person_achievements (indexes ix_ID (ID) and ix_achievement (achievement))
ID int
Sect_ID
Achievement (varchar 250)
```

The Query:

```
select p.* 
from person p
join employer c 
    on c.ID = p.Emp_ID
join person_achievements a 
    on a.Sect_ID = c.Sector_ID
where a.Achievement = 'Employee of the Month'
```

Now I figured the indexes I created would cause this query to perform a LOT better. However, it hasn't. If I remove the join of the person_achievements table and keep the where clause to select, say, the employer name (which is an indexed column also), it takes just over a second to generate 25,000 rows.

What am I missing?

Edit: Added person and employer primary keys

**Edit 2:**

```
"id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
"1","SIMPLE","a","ref","ix_SectID,ix_Achievement,ix_SectID_Achievement","ix_Achievement","253","const","12654","Using where"
"1","SIMPLE","c","ref","PRIMARY,ix_SectID","ix_SectID","8","db.a.Sect_ID","1",""
"1","SIMPLE","p","ref","Emp_ID","Emp_ID","9","db.c.ID","103","Using where"
```

Comment: post the explain - and proper DDLs wouldn't hurt!

Comment: Also, try removing the index on achievement. Instead, put it on (Sect_ID,Achievement)

Comment: Presumably, anything called ID is a PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Added primary - person and employer ID columns are both primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select p.* 
from person p join
     employer c 
     on c.ID = p.Emp_ID join
     person_achievements a 
     on a.Sect_ID = c.Sector_ID
where a.Achievement = 'Employee of the Month';
```

The optimal indexes are:  `person_achievements(Achievement, Sect_id)`, `employer(sector_id, emp_id)`, and `person(emp_id)`.

You can re-arrange inner joins, so you can write the query as:

```
select p.* 
from person_achievements a join
     employer c 
     on a.Sect_ID = c.Sector_ID join
     person p
     on c.ID = p.Emp_ID
where a.Achievement = 'Employee of the Month';
```

This should be how MySQL chooses to process the query with the above indexes.

What I don't understand, though, is why a table called `person_achievements` would not have a column for the `person_id` (in this case `Emp_Id`).  Something seems amiss with either the data structure or the naming.  This misunderstanding might be the heart of the issue.  If there is a person id in that table, then your join may be multiplying the number of rows because it is using the wrong keys.